# Looking up a contact by a phone number

Tags: android, contacts

I am getting contact details for a given phone number using the following code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNum));
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,null,null);
```

There is a case though when the cursor contains 3 records with the same phone number and display name.

Can you please suggest an explanation or possible reason for that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are all 3 phone numbers formatted differently? For example, is one like `(123) 123-1234`, while another is like `123-123-1234`?

Comment: The number appears only once in the Contacts application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain that you don't have the same number entered for 3 different contacts or 3 different contact methods?  You can have multiple contacts with the same numbers and manually merge them in the contacts app.

The URI you are building is a query for the contacts content provider so in the case above it is possible to return more than one contact for a given number.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It's the same contact with the same ID. However, when I select edit contact I see 3 Google contacts with the same phone number and display name. So I guess now the question whether it's possible to define a query that returns no duplicates.

Thanks